# Reference a newly created computed column in the same query where we create it

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
(SUBSTRING(Column1,1,3)) AS ComputedColumn
WHERE ComputedColumn !="dec"
INTO Table2
FROM Table1;
```

This is an example where I have a computed column (which is essentially created by using an expression). If I run this, I get a "column name invalid" error, because I make a reference to the computed column in the same query where I created it.

In an application called SAS, this is solved by prefixing the computed column name in the WHERE clause with the "(CALCULATED)" keyword. Is there a similar solution in Sql Server.
Other than doing this:

```
SELECT 
(SUBSTRING(Column1,1,3)) AS ComputedColumn
WHERE (SUBSTRING(Column1,1,3)) !="dec"
INTO Table2
FROM Table1;
```

Which I know it is possible but very confusing when the expression is very huge. There must be another way to REFERENCE A NEWLY CREATED COMPUTED COLUMN in the same query where we create it.

Thanks a billion! 
Anna

Comment: When we're talking about a `LEFT`, what is the value of trying to reference the alias? Why not just `WHERE Column1 NOT LIKE 'dec%'`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for this:

```
SELECT ComputedColumn 
INTO Table2 
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1,1,3)) CxA(ComputedColumn)
WHERE ComputedColumn !="dec"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it up in a derived table:

```
SELECT *
  INTO Table2
FROM (
  SELECT (SUBSTRING(Column1,1,3)) AS ComputedColumn
  FROM Table1
) t
WHERE ComputedColumn != 'dec'
```

I also change the double quotes to single quoteset because string literals need to be put between single quotes. Double quotes denote column (or table) names.